# java Standalone Client to deploy war file to weblogic 14.1.1

Tags: weblogic, jmx, weblogic12c

Earlier  Java Standalone client with wlfullclient.jar used to deploy the jar file to weblogic server <14x version.
But weblogic server 14.1.1 had deprecated wlfullclient.jar and wlbuilder.jar and replaced with wlthint3client.jar,
Now with wlthint3client.jar, not able to compile the below packages

```
import javax.enterprise.deploy.shared.ModuleType;
import javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.TargetModuleID;
import javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.exceptions.TargetException;
import javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.status.DeploymentStatus;
import javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.status.ProgressEvent;
import javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.status.ProgressListener;
import javax.enterprise.deploy.spi.status.ProgressObject;

import weblogic.deploy.api.spi.DeploymentOptions;
import weblogic.deploy.api.spi.WebLogicDeploymentManager;
import weblogic.deploy.api.spi.WebLogicTarget;
import weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper;
```

reference link : http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=483

After migrating weblogic to 14.1.1, added "wls-api.jar" or "com.oracle.weblogic.deployment.jar" ,"javax.javaee-api.jar"  and "wlthint3client.jar" added to the class path, will all tries getting classnotfound excepitons.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/deploy/api/internal/SPIDeployerLogger
at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.<init>(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:108)
at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.<init>(WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.java:124)
at weblogic.deploy.api.spi.factories.internal.DeploymentFactoryImpl.getDeploymentManager(DeploymentFactoryImpl.java:86)
at wls.api/weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.getRemoteDeploymentManager(SessionHelper.java:580)
```

Is there any other way to implement java standalone client for deploying war to the WebLogic 14.1.1?
notices that weblogic.jar as tons of jars mapped and cannot add many jars.

Comment: The easyiest way is to add weblogic.jar to your classpath but you need a weblogic server installation on the host.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel Colling, thanks for the answer, But the client has to run from different vm not the same vm where weblogic is located. weblogic.jar has manifest with tons of jars listed without any class files.

Comment: So, a better solution could be to use REST Management API to deploy your application. Therefor, you will no longer need WebLogic classes and you will be able to deploy your application from any VM in the network. Read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/standalone/weblogic-server/14.1.1.0/wlrur/using.html#GUID-BB43D597-6DCF-46F2-AC7C-8D7A608B4656) for details.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel Collin, problem with  REST Management API, deploy api cannot take a war file instead absolute path has to be passed, my client has to upload war file from other vm to weblogic server. Is there any other class like WebLogicDeploymentManager in wlthint3client?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using Weblogic Deploy Tooling https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-deploy-tooling/blob/master/site/deploy.md

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic RestFull api has method to pass file so we can deploy with restFull api remotely